# C# OpenFileDialog: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, visio, openfiledialog

I need to programmatically open a document from Sharepoint in Visio. But when I navigate to the network folder, select a document and click on open, I
get the following error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
>   [image]

When searching for the error, I found the following documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms832054.aspx. So I guess that the file name contains illegal characters. I tried to use the FileOk event to overwrite the validation of the fileName:

```
public void openFile() {
    OpenFileDialog sf = new OpenFileDialog();
    sf.FileOk += openFileDialog_FileOk;
    if (sf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var app =(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application)context.Application;
        app.Documents.Open(sf.FileName);
    }
}

private void openFileDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var sfd = sender as OpenFileDialog;
    var file = new FileInfo(sfd.FileName);
    if (file.Name.Contains('#'))
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

but the event does not fire. Using the standard Visio interface it is possible to open files from Sharepoint but the file dialog looks a bit different:
[image]

How can I get a similar file dialog? And so my questions is: how can I programmatically open a Visio document from Sharepoint (network folder)?

Comment: `sender as SaveFileDialog`? Not `OpenFileDialog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Visio does not provide app.GetOpenFilename API, you are out of luck. But you could use another office application for the same. Like Excel for example:

```
var excel = new Excel.Application();
var fileName = excel.GetOpenFilename();
excel.Quit();

var visio = new Visio.Application();
visio.Documents.Open(fileName);
```

which provides a "similar dialog" and "normal url", that is understood by Visio API without any issues.

The problem probably is that Visio API does not understand UNC DAV file path format with @SSL part, that is provided by the default "built-in" OpenFileDialog (or may be something else as well). Check what is the value of the .FileName returned by the default dialog. BTW, to prevent error messages, it's enough to set `sf.CheckFileExists = false`, maybe that will be enough.